# transparent css not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-select, html-input

I have following css to set background of input and dropdown which works in IE and Firefox but doesn't work in chrome:

```
.user-fld input{width:338px !important; margin-bottom:0px !important; height:18px !important; float:right; background-color:transparent !important; color:#FFF !important; border-bottom:1px solid #FFF; border-left:none !important; border-right:none !important; border-top:none !important; /* padding:0 8px; */}

.user-fld select{width:338px; background-image:url(../images/dropdown.png); background-repeat:repeat; border-bottom:1px solid #fff; padding:0 0 7px 0; border-left:none; border-right:none; border-top:none; float:right;color:White;}
```

I am using these to show transparent background. Please suggest solution to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements, such as `<input>` and `<select>`, are traditionally hard to style. Try `-webkit-appearance: none`. Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f7Lme/).

Comment: @DotnetSparrow What do you mean by 'user inputs'?